# Accessing attributes from within recipes

Tags: chef, configuration, configuration-management, infrastructure-as-code

Let us say I do `knife node edit mynode` and within the `normal` section I edit the JSON to add `"myattribute": "myvalue",`. I save this and verify that it has taken effect by issuing `knife search node -a myattribute mynode`, and I see it there. How would I then use this value from within a recipe? I would have expected to just be able to say `node['myattribute']` when running the recipe on `mynode` but that just returns nothing. The usual Ohai attributes such as `node['hostname']` obviously work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that according to chef documentation you should use `normal` with node data.

> A normal attribute is a setting that persists in the node object. A
>   normal attribute has a higher attribute precedence than a default
>   attribute.

you can read about it here:

https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html

https://docs.chef.io/knife_node.html

some example:

```
  "normal": {
    "ebs": {
      "devices": [
        {
          "mount_device": "/dev/xvdf",
          "encrypt": true,
          "volume_mapping": [
            {
              "device": "/dev/xvdf"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

In you recipe:

```
if node.ebs.devices[0]['mount_device'] == '/dev/xvdf' and node.ebs.devices[0]['encrypt'] ...
```

Another example with `node['myattribute']`

```
   "normal": {
        "myattribute": "myvalue"
        },
```

Comment: I've read all the documentation but my question is not answered there - what I am struggling with is accessing an attribute set within the `normal` section from within a recipe.

Comment: check now my answer

Comment: This does not work (and is one of the things I tried before posting the question). I agree it "ought" to as per the docs, but it returns nothing.